# How to get rid of text box selection highlight on Chrome/Safari?

Tags: css

When using Chrome or Safari, an `active text box` or `text area` will display a blue/orange `border` around the box.  I have seen some sites get rid of this, but I have copied their `CSS` and it's still there.  How do I do it?

Comment: Further to this question, I wonder if it's possible to change the color of the outline instead of just removing it? I am in the same position, when the outline occurs, I get an ugly green color. Would be great to change it!

Answer (score 79, accepted):

The following CSS usually removes the default highlight-border:

```
input:focus {outline: none; }
```

It's worth remembering that the outline is a useful visual feedback for the UI focus, for those users not using a mouse (keyboard navigation, for example), and it's worth substituting another visual cue to replace the loss of the outline.

Comment: Thank you!  Yeah, I definitely am...it's just I have a background on the inputs that makes it look ugly.

Comment: @Chris, always a pleasure. And it was a just-in-case reminder, no offence intended =)

Answer (score 16):

You can use

```
input:focus, textarea:focus {
    outline: 0;
}
```

But try to give some indication to the user that the form element is focused, for accessibility reasons.

Comment: Well, I'm gonna +1 you, since we came up with the same answer at the same time...(I'd feel rude otherwise) =)

Answer (score 3):

I just did this :

```
:focus { outline: none; }
```